# Set connect timout using setsockopt in Linux

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket, setsockopt

I am writing a linux Qt5/c++ app that tries to connect to a peer using a QTcpSocket.  I call

```
tcpsocket->connectToHost(address,port,options)
```

When the peer is available it works great and connects immediately.  However, when the peer is not available: The first time I call the above, the connect waits 1 minute before I receive a SocketTimeoutError (5).  Then, every subsequent call to connect might wait a second before I receive a ConnectionRefusedError (0), or might wait a full minute (depending on the system tested).

Is there a setsockopt I can use to reduce the time waiting for initial connect?

I should point out that I already set some socket options in order to quickly notify me of a lost connection (see below).  Hopefully these aren't causing the 1 minute initial connection error delay:

```
int enableKeepAlive = 1;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &enableKeepAlive, sizeof(enableKeepAlive));
int maxIdle = 5; /* seconds */
setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &maxIdle, sizeof(maxIdle));
int count = 3;  // send up to 3 keepalive packets out, then disconnect if no response
setsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &count, sizeof(count));
int interval = 2;   // send a keepalive packet out every 2 seconds (after the 5 second idle period)
setsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &interval, sizeof(interval));
```

Comment: I found one reference on google to setsockopt(socket_handle, SOL_TCP, OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, &option, sizeof(option)) but it won't compile as there is no OP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT (at least not in my headers)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rely on `setsockopt()`, why don't you instead set your socket to non-blocking mode and perform an asynchronous `connect()`.  You'd then block on `select()`, `poll()` or whatever event demultiplexing mechanism you are using, setting the timeout to whatever you desire.  Once it becomes writable you know the connection is complete.

Comment: I already do a non blocking connecting, which results in a socketerror signal.  (Using QT so no select or poll).  I realize I could also run a separate timer to expire in a shorter amount of time, but I'm looking for a socket option.

Comment: @GenerationDSystems: It seems odd that you'd need to set a socket option to make a non-blocking connect timeout at all.  From what I understand [`connectToHost()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#connectToHost) should return immediately with no timeout, and emit the `connected()` signal once the connection has been established.  I did find an [old post about a similar problem](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37051-QTcpSocket-connectToHost%28%29-is-blocking-the-GUI!) to your own that implied it may have been a system/driver problem. Does the problem occur on other platforms?

Comment: I don't think you understand the question.  I wish to set the maximum time the socket will attempt to connect before issuing an error signal.  At the moment that is 1 minutes, I need it < 5 seconds

Comment: Ah okay, my mistake.  AFAIK, there isn't a standard way to do that.  What platform are you on?  Here's one way to do it on Linux, for example: http://www.sekuda.com/overriding_the_default_linux_kernel_20_second_tcp_socket_connect_timeout

Comment: See above "I am writing a linux Qt5/c++ app".  So you are saying that it cannot be done on a per connection basis - it must affect the whole OS only?

Comment: @GenerationDSystems: It looks like you can set the number of `SYN` retransmits at a socket granularity through something like the non-portable `setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_SYNCNT, &syn_cnt, sizeof(syn_cnt))` - see the [tcp(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp) man page - but I don't think that would get your connect timeout to less than 5 seconds since setting the `TCP_SYNCNT` to 1, for example, would give you something like 36 seconds, AFAICT.  I've never tried this before, and just learned about it myself.  YMMV.